# python watchdog: definition of commands in file

Tags: python, python-watchdog

I use grunt and `Gruntfile.js` for watch files and launch test, [like this](https://gist.github.com/juanpabloaj/4dbb58be44ac18b681b1)

```
// Gruntfile.js
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.initConfig({
        watch: {
            grunt: {
                files: ['Gruntfile.js']
            },
            python: {
                files : ['./tests/*.py','./libs/*/*.py'],
                tasks: ['pythontest'],
            },
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('pythontest', function(){
        grunt.util.spawn({
            cmd: 'python',
            args: ['setup.py','test'],
            opts: {stdio: 'inherit'},
        });
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);

};
```

I'm searching a python solution, like [watchdog](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog).

for defition of task and commands, watchdog have some file similar to `Gruntfile.js` ?

Comment: I think you want `watchdog.observers`? : http://pythonhosted.org//watchdog/api.html#module-watchdog.observers - you're trying to map an observation of a change to a function call, yes?

Answer (score 0):

For a single command, use the `watchmedo` script command installed in Python's `watchdog` module:

```
watchmedo shell-command --patterns="*.py" --recursive --command='echo python setup.py test # "${watch_src_path}"'
```